# link is changed when page is loaded

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok I found a previous posting but there was no answer to it. Here is the posting I am having a similar issue : [Why is my HREF address being changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811799/why-is-my-href-address-being-changed)

I am trying to set up a login page and I'm trying to link to my local host for now so I can test it.

the path to my connection file should be as such

```
    ../Connections/my_Localhost_test.php
```

but for some reason when the page is loaded it is showing this as the path name and the page name as this

```
    C://..full path... /TMP4z9j7qnj5c.php
```

I don't understand why it would do that instead of throwing an error about not connecting to the database. I have tested the database connection and it works fine.

I would put this on a jsfiddle but I have multiple pages and I'm not quite sure what would be causing the issue so that I can add it there.

Not sure if this is related but previously I was also having an issue where when I click on a link that is a relative path it was changing the link in relation to the last page not the link that I clicked on, so something like this:

```
    <a href="../myservices/projects.php">link 1</a>
    <a href="../about/myprojects.php">link 2</a>
```

so if I'm on the page from link 1 and click on link 2 it was showing the page as not there because the url was redirecting to the main folder and then not going into the about folder and searching for the page in there.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: For the second problem try using full paths in your href.

Comment: Are you doubleclicking on the file for your page in explorer?

Comment: but I want the relative ones because that is how I set up the database, and no I'm not double clicking on the link. the first problem is when I'm loading the login page it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else was wondering I got a response from Adobe on this issue. I didn't realize that Dreamweaver had this option. Here is their response.

That's a temporary page. It's created specifically for previewing.

You "should" be able to turn it off in the preferences...

Edit > Preferences >select Preview In Browser > uncheck the "Preview using temporary file" checkbox

EDIT: OOps, forgot the Preview In Browser selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can Define base url. Try this code :

```
defined('ROOT_PATH')
|| define('ROOT_PATH',"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].substr($_SERVER ["SCRIPT_NAME"],0, strlen($_SERVER ["SCRIPT_NAME"])-9));
```

And print ROOT_PATH before your href.

Comment: I may try this. I have been doing web design for several years and never run into this problem until recently I'm wondering if there is something in the new javascript or maybe the browsers that is causing an issue. thanks.